# how can a child process update the varaible in father process?

Tags: redis

"version:redis-3.0.2, file:rdb.c, method: int rdbSave(char * filename)", there're some UPDATE action to the global varaible "server":

```c
server.dirty = 0;
server.lastsave = time(NULL);
server.lastbgsave_status = REDIS_OK;
```

I wonder, how can a child process update the varaible in father process? Theoretically, it can't.

Answer (score 0):

rdbSave is run in the foreground in the main event loop thread, hence the update isn't done by a chile process.

Look at rdbSaveBackground for fork implementation.

Comment: In the rdbSaveBackground, the child process forked invokes the rdbSave method and updates the "server"global  variable as I sayed..